# Проблемы с on_message Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

И так, мой бот для Дискорда не выполняет команды. Проблема явно в `on_message`, так как без этой функции он работает исправно.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if (message.content.startswith('rp!')):
        print("Command!") # Не обращайте внимание.. 
        pass
    else:
        print("Default message")
        input = db.show_from_DB(tablename="users", item="messages", member=f"{message.author.mention}") # переменная
        msg = int(str(input[-1])) + 1 # И на это тоже..
        db.update_value_in_DB(tablename="users",item="messages",value=f"{msg}", member=f"{message.author.mention}")
```

Код команды для которой нужен `on_message`

```
@bot.command()
async def stats(ctx):
    try:
        member = ctx.message.author.mention
        player = db.show_from_DB(tablename="users",item="member",member=f"{str(member)}")
        lvl = db.show_from_DB(tablename="users",item="level",member=f"{str(member)}")
        msgs = db.show_from_DB(tablename="users",item="messages",member=f"{str(member)}")
        rate = db.show_from_DB(tablename="users",item="rate",member=f"{str(member)}")
        await ctx.send(f"Игрок: {player[-1]}\nУровень: {lvl[-1]}\nВсего сообщений: {msgs[-1]}\nРепутация: {rate[-1]}")
    except:
        db.insert_into_DB(isMany=False,tablename="users",fields=f"('{ctx.message.author.mention}', 0, 0, 0)")
        member = ctx.message.author.mention
        player = db.show_from_DB(tablename="users", item="member", member=f"{str(member)}")
        lvl = db.show_from_DB(tablename="users", item="level", member=f"{str(member)}")
        msgs = db.show_from_DB(tablename="users", item="messages", member=f"{str(member)}")
        rate = db.show_from_DB(tablename="users", item="rate", member=f"{str(member)}")
        await ctx.send(f"Игрок: {player[-1]}\nУровень: {lvl[-1]}\nВсего сообщений: {msgs[-1]}\nРепутация: {rate[-1]}")
```

Я понимаю что мой код - г.. Но тем не менее он иногда работает.
Не знаю что еще написать.. Надеюсь я все понятно изложил

Comment: тогда какая именно ошибка?

Comment: Ошибки как таковой нету. Есть проблема - бот не отвечает на команды, когда работает метод `on_message`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[С документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await process_commands(message)
    if (message.content.startswith('rp!')):
        print("Command!") # Не обращайте внимание.. 
        pass
    else:
        print("Default message")
        input = db.show_from_DB(tablename="users", item="messages", member=f"{message.author.mention}") # переменная
        msg = int(str(input[-1])) + 1 # И на это тоже..
        db.update_value_in_DB(tablename="users",item="messages",value=f"{msg}", member=f"{message.author.mention}")
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас нету возможности проверить, но думаю это поможет

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайтесь